# Prestashop installation stuck on a redirection loop

Tags: php, redirect, prestashop

I am trying to install prestashop on a vm with os **ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64**
Once **prestashop 1.7.0.4** gets extracted it gets on a loop with redirection on the welcome page 
(url: `example.com/install/index.php?step=welcome`)
I already installed **apache2.4** and **mysql 5.6** (also tried before with **nginx**).
Using Firebug and Firefox i get 21 redirects along with a message in the end **The page isn’t redirecting properly**.
The error seems to come from a function that repeats itself because language isn't set or something else, the file that redirects to the welcome page is located here `prestashop_html\install\controllers\http\welcome.php`

**Screenshot 21 loops**
[image]

**Headers received from server** (along with `Location: index.php?step=welcome`)
[image]

Comment: The problem seems to be at line 55 in the file ``prestashop_html\install\controllers\http\welcome.php`` @ function "Language::downloadAndInstallLanguagePack", while testing it doesn't download at all!

Answer (score 0):

Check your php settings. You need `allow_url_fopen = true`.
Also, you can set the language on install `&language=en`. Another solution is to check the language it's trying to download and download manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your webserver is automatically redirecting http trafic to https.
Because by default Prestashop fresh installs force the use of http, it can lead to an infinite loop (conflict between your web serveur and Prestashop settings).